# Nodejs return Asynchronously result as an array

Tags: node.js

in my server application i have some method such as:

1. insert message when user joined to application(`insertUserJoinedMessageAndSendMessage`)
2. get unique id of owner mobile numbers (`getOwnerPhoneNumberUniqueIds`)
3. print generated data

in this solution i have:

```
insertUserJoinedMessageAndSendMessage(userPhoneNumbers, assignedUserId.id)
    .then(function (t) {
        return getOwnerPhoneNumberUniqueIds(userPhoneNumbers);
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        log.info(result);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        log.info(error);
    });
```

methods, `insertUserJoinedMessageAndSendMessage` method work fine without any problem, i want to get generated data on nested Promise as `getUserId()` from `getOwnerPhoneNumberUniqueIds()` Promise function, but i can't print data on this part of code as `log.info(result);` because i can't return array from `getOwnerPhoneNumberUniqueIds()`

```
function insertUserJoinedMessageAndSendMessage(userPhoneNumbers, ownerUserId) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let query = "INSERT INTO `userJoinedMobileNumbers` (`id`, `userId`, `nameAndFamily`, `mobileNumber`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ";
        userPhoneNumbers.map(function (curr) {
            query += "(NULL, " + ownerUserId + ", " + curr.contactName + ", " + curr.contactPhone + ", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),";
        });
        query = query.substr(0, query.length - 1) + ";";
        connection.query(query, function (err, results) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve(true);
        });
    });
}

function getOwnerPhoneNumberUniqueIds(data) {
    return Promise.all(data.map(function (curr) {
        return getUserId(curr.contactPhone)
            .then(function (data) {
                log.info("1) " + data);
                return {id: data};
            });
    })).then(function (accountNumbers) {
        log.info("2) " + accountNumbers);
        return accountNumbers
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

function getUserId(contactPhone) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var query = "SELECT id FROM sendMessageUserJoined WHERE `phoneNumber` ='" + contactPhone + "'";

        connection.query(query, function (err, results) {
            if (err) return reject(err);

            if (results.length > 0) {
                log.info("0) " + results[0].id);
                resolve(results[0].id);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

in `log.info("0) " + results[0].id);` i get result of sql command and that return `id` successful to `getOwnerPhoneNumberUniqueIds()` and i can print result with this part of code as `log.info("1) " + data);`, now how can i return that on:

```
.then(function (accountNumbers) {
    log.info("2) " + accountNumbers);
    return accountNumbers
})
```

`log.info("2) " + accountNumbers);`

dont print result which returned by `return {id: data};`

Comment: `query += "(NULL, " + ownerUserId + ", " + curr.contactName + ", " + curr.contactPhone + ", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),";` screams SQL injection to me. Please consider using a proper SQL library to handle that for you.

Comment: @kouak this is not important when i can't return result to parent, no problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `getUserId`.

In some cases you wouldn't resolve or reject the promise. So your `Promise.all` returned promise maintained pending.

```
function getUserId(contactPhone) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var query = "SELECT id FROM sendMessageUserJoined WHERE `phoneNumber` ='" + contactPhone + "'";

        connection.query(query, function (err, results) {
            if (err) return reject(err);

            if (results.length > 0) {
                log.info("0) " + results[0].id);
                resolve(results[0].id);
            }
            else { //this part is missing
               resolve(); //or reject
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I can't understand whats your mean, because of i get returned result and print that with `log.info("1) " + data);` could you fix my code?